# How to print doc file on a5 page using Java?

Tags: java, swing, printing

I have a doc file as ByteArrayInputStream. I need to print it on a A5 page. I don`t want to hardcode any driver or printer name. I want a dialog to open to select the printer and other printer details. Can anyone help with this ?

Comment: You need to break a big problem like this down into smaller pieces. As far as I can tell, you have at least four sub-problems to solve: Figure out what printers are available, prompt the user to select one, convert the doc (I assume that you mean a Microsoft Word document) file into a format that the printer understands, send the converted data to the selected printer. You might start with checking out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/PrintServiceLookup.html

Comment: I am able to create a doc or pdf file using ByteArrayInputStream. I want to print that file using a popup where all the existing printers configured in system are displayed as dropdown and i can select and print the file.

Comment: Like I said above, you need to break your goal down into sub-problems. Java can't just print an arbitrary input stream to a printer.